# Add specific library from android SDK to unity project

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, applovin

I'm trying to add Applovin Ads to the unity project and there is a new required to add play service sdks

> Add Google Play Services to your App
>
> Due to new requirements by Google, you'll need to integrate the Google
> Play Services SDK into your app.
>
> This is mandatory; without Google Play Services, the SDK cannot
> function.

when I contact applovin, they ask me to add this library to my project

`com.google.android.gms:play-services-games`

how can I do it? I'm not using an android studio, export directly from the unity engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answer from applovin

If you aren't already using a custom mainTemplate.gradle, you can enable it in the `Android PlayerSettings` under `Publishing>Custom Main Gradle Template.`
Add this line to your `mainTemplate.gradle` file:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:16.0.0'
```

Example:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:16.0.0'
**DEPS**}
```

these steps work for any SDK implementations, Consider yourself inside Gradle file.